# Extract Qualitative information from annual report commentary and disclosure

Tags: equities, fundamentals, investing, nlp

Can anyone give idea on the value of latent information in annual report commentary and disclosure. It would be interesting to hear from analyst on how much time they spend reading through annual report of companies they cover and is there any aspect of it they would like automate with a text processing AI program(NLP).

Are there any opportunities in using Natural Language Processing to extract (Qualitative to quantitative) information from

1. Notes to consolidated statement
2. CFO/Finance Head's statement

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly but is certainly relevant when it comes to "the value of latent information": "Our findings indicate that increasing machine and AI readership, proxied by machine downloads, motivates firms to prepare filings that are more friendly to machine parsing and processing" - https://www.nber.org/papers/w27950.